# Can these Ansible tasks in a playbook somehow be merged into one task?

Tags: ansible

I have the following 2 tasks in a playbook:

```
  - name: Check if SSH is running on port 22
    shell: netstat -tunlp | grep ":22 " | sed -e 's/.*\///' | sort -u
    register: ssh_running

  - name: Exit if SSH is not running
    meta: end_play
    when: ssh_running.stdout | trim | lower != "sshd"
```

Do I have to register the variable and check it, or is it possible to combine them as 1 task? Something like:

```
  - name: Check if SSH is running on port 22
    shell: netstat -tunlp | grep ":22 " | sed -e 's/.*\///' | sort -u
    meta: end_play
    when: output_of_shell_command | trim | lower != "sshd"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible. Module [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html#wait-for-waits-for-a-condition-before-continuing) will do the job in one task.

```
- wait_for:
    port: 22
    host: 10.1.0.51
    timeout: 3
    msg: SSH is not running. End of play.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, Vladimi, and thanks for pointing out "wait_for". I've replaced my original task with that.